# ServiceStack (5.5.0) - When testing a ServiceStackController Gateway is null and throws an exception

Tags: servicestack

Using ServiceStack (v 5.5.0) I read the recommended approach to calling services via a controller is by using the Gateway.
Full example is found at https://github.com/RhysWilliams647/ServiceStackControllerTest

```
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = Gateway.Send<TestServiceResponse>(new TestServiceRequest());
            IndexModel model = new IndexModel { Message = response.Message };

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

However when testing my controller via xUnit I get a null exception error as Gateway is null.  Below is my AppHost

```
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {

        public AppHost() : base("Test", typeof(TestService).Assembly)
        {

        }

        public override IServiceGateway GetServiceGateway(IRequest req) =>
            base.GetServiceGateway(req ?? new BasicRequest());

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                HandlerFactoryPath = "api"
            });


            container.RegisterFactory<HttpContext>(() => HttpContext.Current);
            // register container for mvc
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
        }
    }
```

And my test

```
[Trait("Category", "Controllers")]
    [Collection("AppHostFixture")]
    public class ControllerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void CanCallHomeControllerIndex()
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();
            controller.Index();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please advise how to test a ServiceStackController calling the service gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppSelfHostBase` on .NET Framework is a HttpListener self-host which doesn't support MVC so you're not going to be able to run any integration tests.

When you new an MVC controller instance like this:

```
var controller = new HomeController();
```

It's `base.HttpContext` required by `ServiceStackController` doesn't exist, it requires a ASP.NET HttpContext but the self-host in unit test is running on a self-hosted HttpListener server.

You could try accessing the Gateway via the `HostContext` singleton i.e:

```
var gateway = HostContext.AppHost.GetServiceGateway(new BasicRequest());
var response = gateway.Send<TestServiceResponse>(new TestServiceRequest());
```

In this example it calls the Gateway with a mock Http Request Context to simulate a request, but you wont be able to execute real MVC integration tests with a self-hosted Http Listener.

Comment: No problem. So what is the recommended approach to unit testing a mvc controller which is calling Gateway? I don't have to use AppSelfHostBase.

Comment: Use .NET Core as you're able to run a real ASP .NET Core MVC App running on Kestrel otherwise you'd need to launch an IIS Express instance and run integration tests against that remote instance.

Comment: I personally use a gateway mock to test my ASP.NET MVC controllers. Then I use another test project to test my services.